# js jQuery - variable class names

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggleclass

I have some images with classes like: 
.1a 
.2a 
.3a 
.4a 
 .....

I'd like to toggle some classes called 
.1b
.2b
.3b
.. and so on

so that:
 '.1a' --> toggleClass '1b'
'.2a' --> toggleClass '2b' 
..etc

How to do it writing the less? this is my simple code:

```
$(".mini1").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass( "mini_1b" );
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/toygp9v0/1/

Answer (score 0):

You can just get the number and use it for the second selector

```
$("[class^='mini']").click(function() {
     $(this).toggleClass( 'mini_' + this.className.slice(-1) + 'b' );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `data-target`. Assign the property "data-target" to the element that will be clicked which references the element that will be handled.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/710qj9ca/

Note that you can access the `data-target` attribute with `this.dataset.target` to access it directly from the element's property set or by using jQuery's "attr" selector `$(this).attr('data-target')`